# Touchpad isn't working on my netbook

Tags: touchpad, 14.04

I just installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 14.04 and everything is working fine but the touchpad of my laptop isn't working at all, My netbook is a Lanix Neuron LT.
When I had Windows 8 my touchpad was working fine.

Comment: Did it work with 13.10?

Comment: I didn't tried with 13.10, but i used Elementary OS Luna and it didn't work either